# Nosetest: Does it set the errorlevel to 1 on failure?

Tags: python, nose

Windows environment, python 2.7, latest nosetest.

Looking at nosetest docs, and googling around, nowhere do I see that nosetest sets the cmd line errorlevel on test failure.

We need this so that our build system can detect test failure.

Questions are:

- Does Nosetest set the cmd line, errorlevel?  (if so, where are docs)
- If not, what is the appropriate way to handle this? (must my build parse some log output, or?)

Comment: Best advice is probably to make a test case: one that trivially fails, and see what it does. Too bad the docs are missing.

Comment: @jpaugh That is a fair and easy call. I post the question here because testing frameworks are critical path. (The tests need to be more valid than the code being tested, or the whole thing cannot be trusted....) We prefer (strongly) to rely on documented features, as they are more likely to be stable over time. (Imagine a future ver of nosetest that does not set errorlevel, and then our build passes when tests actually fail.) In a sense, this thread is a question: Why is this aspect, crucial to build environments, not documented?

Answer (score 2):

`%errorlevel%` on windows is the return code of the application, typically the argument given to the `exit(int)` call (exit code). These return codes are the same as [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html?highlight=unittest#module-unittest), but the documentation is not very explicit:

> The testRunner argument can either be a test runner class or an already created instance of it. By default main calls sys.exit() with an exit code indicating success or failure of the tests run.

In the above sentence *By default* is to understand as *if the call argument `exit` is not set to `False`*:

> main supports being used from the interactive interpreter by passing in the argument exit=False. This displays the result on standard output without calling sys.exit()

*(New in 2.7 and 3.1. In older version, `sys.exit` is always called.)*

I found no special documentation about the return code, but looking at the source, one can find that exit code is [0 for success, 1 for error](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/core.py#L210) (same for [unittest alone](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2d62ee3c7617/Lib/unittest/main.py#l246)) and [2 if the usage help has to be printed](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2d62ee3c7617/Lib/unittest/main.py#l101) (given arguments when calling as standalone program are incorrect). Specific for nose, when program is asked to [display version](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/core.py#L154) or [list plugins](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/core.py#L158), exit code is 0 too.

Comment: I think we can all agree that "usually its 0 for success" -- the issue I am hitting is that I can't find docs that discusses how it is handled in a nose/unittest world. (I don't like going out on limbs with something this important)

Comment: Update the answer, I hope it helps you further.